# HTML5 srcset and sizes downloading 2 images

Tags: html, image, responsive-images, srcset

I want to download the 80w image on screens with a max-width of 991px and the 160w image on screens with a min-width of 992px.

With the code below both images are downloaded on screens with a max-width of 991px, what is wrong?

```
   <img src="img-160.jpg" 
     srcset="img-160.jpg 160w, img-80.jpg 80w"
     sizes="(max-width: 991px) 80px, (min-width: 992px) 160px">
```

Comment: Is the other image downloading on it's "should be 992 as min" browser? @GabrielSouza

Comment: Yes, it's downloading

Comment: I have added an alternate route to take. @GabrielSouza

Comment: FYI: The media condition should be omitted on the last part of your `sizes` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-sizes). This should give you `sizes="(max-width: 991px) 80px, 160px"`. I don’t think this is the cause of your double-loading problem, however